# How to read all files from a zip file

Tags: java, groovy, zip

I'd like to recursively read a zip file and then extract all files in a separate folder.

For example if `some.zip` file has the following contents:

```
file5.txt
somefolder
  file.txt
  file4.txt
inside.zip 
  file2.txt
  file3.txt
```

What I want is just all the files, including all the files in zip files inside the zip file (`inside.zip` in the example above).

end result of `somefolder` would be all the files (I don't care about the folder structure):

```
file5.txt
file.txt
file4.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

**What I tried:**

I have the code below but it maintains the folder structure and does not open zip files inside zip files:

```
import java.util.zip.*
def extractZip (String zipFile) {
    def zipIn = new File(zipFile)
    def zip = new ZipFile(zipIn)

    zip.entries().findAll { !it.directory }.each { e ->
        (e.name as File).with{ f ->
            f.parentFile?.mkdirs()
            f.withOutputStream { w ->
                w << zip.getInputStream(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you'd need to actually test what you're extracting, e.g. `if (file being extracted = '.zip') { open(file being extracted); }`

Comment: What's a ZipFile? Is that a custom class?

Comment: @AlvinBunk import java.util.zip.*

Comment: @Anthony, You should import it when presenting an example.

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate through the entries
- If the file is not a .zip file then extract it
- If the file is a zip file then get the inputStream for its entry. Create a new ZipInputStream. Extract the stream.

  ```
  public void extract(ZipInputStream zipFile, File outputDir) throws IOException
  {
  ZipEntry entry;
  while  ( ( entry = zipFile.getNextEntry()) != null)
  {
     if (entry.isDirectory())
       continue;
     if (entry.getName().endsWith(".zip"))
     {
         extract(new ZipInputStream(zipFile), outputDir);
     }
     else
     {
         extractToDir(zipFile, new File (outputDir, entry.getName()));

     }

  }
  }

  private void extractToDir(ZipInputStream zipFile, File outFile) throws       FileNotFoundException
  {
        ByteStreams.copy(zipFile, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
  }



  public static void main(String... args)
  {
       extract(new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFileName)), new File("outputPath"));
  }
  ```

Comment: This doesn't work when the zip file has a filer as in the example I showed.

Comment: Edited if you want to skip the folders.
Just add
 if (entry.isDirectory())
     continue;